# How can I deploy shiny in docker?

Tags: r, docker, amazon-ec2, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app that is running on an EC2 instance that I'd like to deploy in docker. Running the shiny app on localhost (so the EC2 instance) works fine, albeit it takes ~5 minutes to load.

However, I've been told to run the following command to get the website running:

`sudo docker run --rm -p $PORT:1234         --mount type=bind,source=/mnt/compbio/jupyter_s3contents/web/dashboard,target=/srv/shiny-server/        --mount type=bind,source=/mnt/compbio/jupyter_s3contents/,target=/home/rstudio/compbio/        --mount type=bind,source=/var/log/shiny-server/,target=/var/log/shiny-server/        shiny`

However, all I get is the following output, and it doesn't run beyond this point.

````
[2020-11-10T15:25:36.498] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.13.944 (Node.js v12.15.0)
[2020-11-10T15:25:36.503] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2020-11-10T15:25:36.533] [WARN] shiny-server - Running as root unnecessarily is a security risk! You could be running more securely as non-root.
[2020-11-10T15:25:36.536] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on http://[::]:1234```

I am new to docker, any idea what I am doing wrong here?
````

Comment: it looks like you're spinning up a Shiny server which is listening for connections on port 1234. However, there's something unusual about your command - it doesn't seem to include a docker image name. You would need to open this port in EC2 if you want to try it out. Two best options for hosting Shiny apps - https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny or https://www.shinyproxy.io/ - both have advantages and disadvantages